# error when running script for telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERPC\Desktop\Karasbomb\Vizione\main.py", line 1162, in <module>
    @dp.throttled(anti_flood,rate=3)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Dispatcher' object has no attribute 'throttled'. Did you mean: 'throttle'?
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000020D4CA6B530>
```

Comment: What is the `dp` module?  Is the message correct -- did you intend to use "throttle" instead?